# Disable touches touchMoved cocos2d v3?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touches, user-interaction

I am trying to do something fairly simple in Cocos2d 3.1. I am receiving touch events on a CCSprite subclass and I am trying to stop receiving touch events when the touch is slid off of the sprite using a simple `containsTouchLocation` helper method.

What is not working however is if I do `self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` in the `touchMoved:` method, it still calls touchMoved!

This is my full touchMoved: method:

```
- (void)touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    int color = ([self containsTouchLocation:touch] ? 128 : 255);
    self.color = [CCColor colorWithCcColor3b:ccc3(color, color, color)];
}
```

Why is it that even though I am clearly trying to turn off touch events in the touchMoved method, it is still calling it?

Comment: does it maybe only affect the current touch, ie interaction disabled only takes effect for future touches while the current touch is allowed to receive moved and ended events?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Yes it appears it stops all future touches. How would I stop the current touch?

Comment: From what I researched, there isn't a way to do this. So for the meantime I just used a BOOL and won't call the code when need be. Do you know if there is a way to stop touch events for a touch that is still in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivating `userInteractionEnabled` on an active touch does not cancel a touch in the current version of Cocos2D. I have created a pull request to change that, because in my opinion nodes should only receive touch events while `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES`(https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/882)

For now you will have to handle that with some sort of state variable in your node that receives touches.

Comment: Thanks! I can see both sides to be honest but your commit works very well.

Comment: Yes, I can see both sides, too ;)